# Getting attribute error ='NoneType' object has no attribute 'content'

Tags: python, django

I am adding api to my views.py in my app. and facing some attribute error

from django.shortcuts import render

```
def home(request):
    import requests
    import json
    api_request = request.POST.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/news/?lang=EN")
    api = json.loads(api_request.content)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {"api": api})
```

Expected output is the data which is being fetch from the api. 
Getting error
AttributeError at /
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content'

Answer (score 1):

You mixed *`request`* parameter which is the request object of the view, and `requests`. You probably want to use:

```
import requests
import json

def home(request):
    api_request = requests.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/news/?lang=EN')
    api = json.loads(api_request.content)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'api': api})
```

Note that you can use `.json()` to automatically decode the JSON blob:

```
from requests import get as reget

def home(request):
    api_request = reget('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/news/?lang=EN')
    api = api_request.json()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'api': api})
```